# Visual Studio & C# Analyse Method

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a method which calls lots of other methods and I want to inspect why this method pulls back so much data...

I need to find who the culprit(s) are and how in Visual Studio 2015 (Ultimate) I can easily find where the problem is

```
public  Client BuildClient(string id)
{
    var a = client.Find(id)
    var t = transactions.FindAllByClient(string id)
    //other methods....
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Im guessing that 'client' and 'transactions' are static objects? you have neglected to post that logic, we dont know what they actually do. In response to your question about finding the problem, have you tried setting breakpoints on your code to see whats actually being returned?

Comment: Hi I was just demoing some code, i have about 15+ method calls and wanted to know a handy and quick way of seeing what method is using the most data.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the Ultimate version:
You could wrap your method in a UnitTest and then use the Profiling feature (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx)